# Is there any way to store Inet addresses of multiclient connections in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there any way to store Inet addresses of multiple connections and compare with each new inetaddress in java. so that already connected client will not be connected again.

Comment: Which technology do you use? Sockets/HTTP or?

Comment: Sure, there is a way to store [previously seen values of any type, including InetAddress], and compare whether a particular value has been seen before. Usually a Map is best suited for this purpose.

Comment: thankz. we use socket and it worked properly...